# Concept specifying reference argument of method

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code does not compile:

```
struct FooImpl {
   using Bar = int;
   void method(Bar&) {}
 };
 
 template <typename F>
 concept Foo = requires(F f) {
   { f.method(typename F::Bar{}) };
 };
 
 static_assert(Foo<FooImpl>);
```

The problem comes from the `&` in the `FooImple::method()` declaration. Removing the `&` fixes the problem.

Instead of changing `FooImpl`, I would like to change `Foo`. How can I change the concept implementation to satisfy the `static_assert`?

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the concept is to see if `F` has a member function named `method` that can accept an lvalue of type `F::Bar`, then what you want to write is:

```cpp
template <typename F>
concept Foo = requires (F f, typename F::Bar arg) {
    f.method(arg);
};
```

This will gracefully fail if there is no `typename F::Bar` also (i.e. `Foo<int>` is `false`, not ill-formed).

Comment: Great, that works. Out of curiosity, is it possible to write the concept so that it accepts `method(Bar&)` but rejects `method(Bar)`?

Comment: @dshin Not... really. I mean, you could check the type of `&F::method` (if it happens to be not a template and not an overload set and doesn't have default arguments) but the premise of C++20 concepts is that you check expression validity, so that's `f.method(arg)`

Comment: @dshin You could potentially combine this one with what you have originally: https://godbolt.org/z/Ysbded6P5

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Creative! Wish there was a way to do that in a way that more clearly communicates the requirement to a human reader...

Comment: @dshin It might just be the names of each concepts, if you change the names to something like `only_ref_func = have_ref_func<T> && !have_value_func<T>`, it feels pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep That feels a bit jarring to me, as I have generally been writing my concepts to mirror class declarations as closely as possible, with a mental model that `concept` is c++'s analog to Java's `interface`. But as Barry points out, the premise of concepts is something different. So I think this highlights to me that I have to rethink the "concept" of concepts.

Comment: @dshin Not too familiar with Java's interface, but it seems the same as C++ [abstract class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class). `concept` is more of a boolean expression operated on the types. And `requires` expression is a function that yields true/false based on if all statements in it is valid.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Java actually has abstract classes which map exactly to c++ abstract classes. Java interfaces are similar in purpose to c++ concepts. Syntax-wise, however, in Java, you can essentially just replace `class` with `interface` in a class declaration, and instantly have a valid interface. My hope was that extracting a concept from a class declaration in c++ would be equally effortless, but that appears to not have been a goal in the design of concepts.